# How to distinguish rpm package files from files generated by make install

Tags: centos7, rpm, make

What I have:

1. CentOS 7 based server
2. Part of files (programs) set from sources (configure && make install)
3. No kind of sources left (no spec files, nothing)

What I need:

- remove these programs set from sources and keep their config files.
- install same software from rpm packages, lets say with rpm -ihv or -Uhv
- yum to keep tracking of files and user friendly uninstall possible.

How can I distinguish which files were created by make install, and files that were created during an RPM package installation?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I think your question isn't very clear until the third section. (It's fairly low-quality in the current state.) Try rephrasing the question to lead off with that instead and you might have a more favorable response.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer, perhaps it will help someone.

```
find / -type f -exec rpm -qf {} + | grep "not owned"
```

feel free to adjust both parts of expression to your situation

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you messed up and what you actually want to accomplish as an end result, it will be difficult for anyone to help.  It sounds like you want to clean up an RPM installation that got stomped on by a `make install` (or vice versa) but it might help to know what you were trying to install.

Without knowing more details, my suggestion is to attempt to uninstall whatever you installed, both RPM and from source, then start over.